# How to detach Postman console into a separate window?

Tags: postman

I'm using Postman 9.1.3 in Windows 10. I had Postman console as a separate window. Then after a power outage and sudden PC reset it is now only available as a pane within the main window, and I can't seem to find a setting to detach it.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 => `Ctrl + Alt + C`

---

[image]

[image]

*Tested and checked now on Postman for Linux 8.12.5 and Postman for Windows 9.1.3*

Comment: here this only opens the console in the pane, i need to detach into separate window

Comment: @tester11 Really ? I open and I have a new window ... Win 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 after pressing the combination a new window appears.

Comment: which postman version do you have (settings->about)? maybe its this newest 9.1.3 update broke it? i dont have "new console window" entry in settings-> shortcuts. and there's no detach arrow in top right in pane view

Comment: @tester11  Postman for Windows Version 9.1.3 Check out shortcuts maybe they are disabled?? or you have problem with keyboard ??

Comment: i now tried clean postman reinstall, twice, each time also deleting all settings in AppData Roaming and Local. after official installer Postman-win64-8.12.5-Setup.exe from their website console window works, then it updates to 9.0.9, console window still works, then it updates to 9.1.3 and that breaks it, in that latest version console only opens within a pane and there's no option to detach it. it's so strange on your computer there's no such problem with the same version

Comment: I have the same issue.  And it appears no way to prevent automatic "minor update".  @tester11 and MarioG8, have you guys opened bug on postman git issues?

Comment: Thanks for all your guys' help, at least now I have a usable app again.  Issue opened (10426).  BTW, you can disable update using hosts file, but have to time it right after the first update but before the second one.  

0.0.0.0         dl.pstmn.io
0.0.0.0         sync-v3.getpostman.com
0.0.0.0         getpostman.com
0.0.0.0         go.pstmn.io

Answer (score 3):

According to Postman folks, view console in separate window is only available when signed in, since 9.1